# Decrease and Optimize bundle with two entry points with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have two entry points and use Webpack 4, but the build for production takes about 3-5 minutes and create for both entry points two large `vendor` output js files. Looks like I have:

For one entry:

```
main.4b8e36a69d37fde00916.js   1.15 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
vendors~main.ebc7e19767bc133dd354.js   5.36 MiB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendors~main
```

For second:

```
../identityServerModel.cc17842eb2ee86c9a5a7.js   17.2 KiB       0  [emitted]         identitySer
../vendors~main.6adcd3c3d6680968397f.js   4.24 MiB       2  [emitted]  [big]  vendors~main
```

How to optimize it? Do you have any suggestions and workaround or tricks?
When I start my `build` script I run two builds for this entry points.

**package.json:**

```
...
"build": "webpack --colors --config webpack/prod.js && webpack --config webpack/identityServer.js &&   cpx \"dist/**/*\" ../SomeFolder/Ui --clean",
...
```

*My webpack:*

*common.js:*

```
const extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

const path = require('path')
// initialize version.js
require('child_process').exec('node ' + path.resolve('./../scripts/setAppVersion.js'), {cwd: '../'}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(err)
})

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.js',
    plugins: [
        // TODO remove after deleting *.scss files across app
        new extractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true,
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {
            root: path.join(__dirname, '..'),
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'eslint-loader?{fix:true}',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                enforce: 'pre',
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
            },
            // TODO remove extractTextPlugin after delete all .scss in react-components
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader!sass-loader',
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|mp4)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    performance: {hints: false},
    optimization: {splitChunks: {chunks: 'all'}},
}
```

**fist entry point config:**

*prod.js:*

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const common = require('./common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: false,
    stats: 'normal',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.ejs',
            hash: true,
        }),
    ],
})
```

**second entry point:**

*identityServer.js:*

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

const common = require('./common.js')
const path = require('path')

const templates = {
    index: {excludeChunks: ['identityServerModel']},
    logout: {
        excludeChunks: ['main'],
        chunks: ['identityServerModel'],
        inject: 'head',
    },
    error: {
        excludeChunks: ['main'],
        chunks: ['identityServerModel'],
    },
}

const entryHtmlPlugins = Object.keys(templates).map(template => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: `./src/components/loginPage/${template}.ejs`,
    filename: `${template}.html`,
    hash: true,
    ...templates[template],
}))

const commonFiltered = {
    ...common,
}

commonFiltered.plugins = commonFiltered.plugins.filter(plugin => !(plugin instanceof CleanWebpackPlugin))

module.exports = merge(commonFiltered, {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: false,
    stats: 'normal',
    entry: {
        identityServerModel: './src/components/loginPage/identityServerModel.js',
        main: './src/components/loginPage/login.js',
    },
    plugins: entryHtmlPlugins,
    output: {
        filename: '../[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/login'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
})
```

I have main project and I bundle all vendros in `prod.js` and server page in `identetyServer.js` each of this entries has similar vendors (react, redux and all this stuff). For me  vendor bundles looks similar for both entries.

Comment: it would be good to use bundle analyzer and build it targetting production, and have a look at the output, what is that big, what is duplicated between those two vendor modules, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to speed up webpack, but there is one that should be considered first:

Remove scss/postcc processing from webpack if you are going to "drop it out" from bundle with `extract-text-webpack-plugin` . I do not know any good reason to process css in webpack if you are going to reference it in the html with `link`.

Alternatively you can do something the same with "incremental" style webpack build processes. But IMHO one "step back" is the most simple way.